# error in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i wrote this plugin for menu with jquery
this plugin success work in Chrome but not correctly work in IE or other browser...
error has this:
 when i click in menu, menu open but when hover the sub menu sub menu do not open
this error has for all browser except Chrome...
in chrome this menu work correctly sub menu opened when hover

```
$(function () {
    $.fn.extend({
        hMenu: function (options) {

            var settings = {
                menuItem: '',
                subMenuSelector: 'div.sub-menu',
                subSubMenuSelector: 'div.sub-menu ul li',
                opp: 'a.outdoor',
                closeDuration: 150,
                openDuration: 350
            };
            var style = {
                "display": "block",
                clear: "both"
            }


            if (options != null) {
                $.extend(settings, options);
            }
            var _base = $(this);
            var _id = "";
            init();

            function init() {
                if (settings.menuItem == '' || settings.subMenuItem == '') { return; }
                $(settings.menuItem, _base).each(function () {
                    if ($(settings.subMenuSelector, $(this).parent()).length > 0) {
                        $(this).click(function () {
                            $(settings.subMenuSelector + ':visible', _base).fadeOut(settings.closeDuration);
                            if ($(settings.subMenuSelector, $(this).parent()).is(':visible')) {
                                $(settings.subMenuSelector, $(this).parent()).slideUp(settings.closeDuration);
                                $('html').unbind('click');
                            }
                            else {
                                //Show My Sub menu
                                $(settings.subMenuSelector, $(this).parent()).fadeIn(settings.openDuration);

                                $(settings.subMenuSelector, $(this).parent()).click(function () {
                                    cancelEvent();
                                });


                                // And Do not anything else !!!!!! (cancel event !)
                                cancelEvent();
                                //                                $(settings.subSubMenuSelector).click(function () {
                                //                                    $(settings.subMenuSelector).animate({ width: "700px", height: "700px" });
                                //                                   
                                //                                })
                                if (settings.subSubMenuSelector == "") { return; }
                                //                                $(settings.subSubMenuSelector).mouseover(function () { 
                                //                                      $(this).css("color","red"); 
                                //                                    }); 
                                $(settings.subSubMenuSelector).hover(function () {
                                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                                    _id = id;
                                    $("a." + id + "").show(function () {
                                        $('a.' + id + '').css('display', 'block');
                                    }); //show callback
                                    //alert(id);

                                }, function () {
                                    $('a.' + _id + '').hide('slow');
                                }); //subsubmenuselector.hover
                                //If user clicke on html , close current sub-menu
                                $('html').bind('click', function () {
                                    $(settings.subMenuSelector, $(this).parent()).fadeOut(settings.closeDuration);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            function cancelEvent() {
                if (event && event.stopPropagation) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                else if (e && e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // DOM style
                }
                else { // IE hack
                    window.event.cancelBubble = true;
                }
            }
        } //function
    }); //plugin definition
});
```

Comment: Can you put the code in jsfiddle

Comment: Why do you have a cancelEvent function when jQuery has that built in? Also e is undefined so you should be getting an error there!

Comment: why are you doing this $('a.' + id + '').css('display', 'block'); when jquery show() already does that for you.